# SecretClient.GetSecret always throws 400 error

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I am trying to move from the old "Microsoft.Azure.KeyValut" package to the new "Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets"

I can list all my secrets, but the moment I try to obtain a secret value I get and 400 Http status error:

> Azure.RequestFailedException: 'Service request failed. Status: 400
> (Bad Request)
>
> Content: {"error":{"code":"BadParameter","message":"Method GET does
> not allow operation 'ChilkatUnlock'"}}

```
internal SecretClient GetClient() {
            var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(cKvUri), new ClientSecretCredential(cAzureTennantId, cAzureClientId, cAzureClientSecret));
            return client;
}

internal void ListSecrets() {
            var client = GetClient();
            

            Pageable<SecretProperties> allSecrets = client.GetPropertiesOfSecrets();

            foreach (SecretProperties secretProperties in allSecrets) {
                Console.WriteLine(secretProperties.Name);
                var val = client.GetSecret(secretProperties.Name);
                Console.WriteLine(val.Value);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try with the code in your issue, and it returns secrets without error. Please check your `ChilkatUnlock` method. I share the Access policies at last.

```
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(cKvUri), new ClientSecretCredential(cAzureTennantId, cAzureClientId, cAzureClientSecret));

Pageable<SecretProperties> allSecrets = client.GetPropertiesOfSecrets();

foreach (SecretProperties secretProperties in allSecrets)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Secret: " + secretProperties.Name);
     var val = client.GetSecret(secretProperties.Name);
     Console.WriteLine("Value: " + val.Value);
}
```

[image]

**Access policies:**

[image]

Comment: Turned out my keyvault Uri was wrong. It contained `/secrets/` at the end. This worked in the deprecated version "Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault" but not in the new version.

Comment: For more info, the uri format as `https://{vault-name}.vault.azure.net/`. And the sample is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/tutorial-net-create-vault-azure-web-app#update-the-code).